# Views are not accessible in kotlin file, Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to access the EditText and button from xml file to kotlin file, but it's not working i have tried to import the view. It doesn't work. This android keyword is giving the error(Unresolved reference: android)

```
    import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TodoViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val currentTodo = todos[position]
    holder.itemView.apply {

        edTodoTitle.text = currentTodo.title
        btnAddTodo.ischecked = currentTodo.isChecked
        }
    }
```

Here is the second file
data class Todo(
val title: String,
val isChecked: Boolean= false
)
Here is the xml file

```
 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/etTodoTitle"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Enter Todo Title"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnAddTodo"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnAddTodo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add Todo"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnDltTodo" />

enter code here
enter code here
```

Comment: Kotlin synthetic accessors (`kotlinx.android.synthetic`) are deprecated and probably are not enabled in your project. Please use [view binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding).

Answer (score 0):

```
  This may be the issue:
```

edTodoTitle.text = currentTodo.title

Try changing the edTodo
to etTodo